# How to design a User Interface on Telegram App, triggered using a Bot Just like @ShopBot in Java?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, bots, telegram-bot

Am very fascinated on how this Telegram Bot called [@ShopBot](https://t.me/shopbot)
is being developed and i want to implement a bot that actually looks like the [@ShopBot](https://t.me/shopbot)
.There is a section of the Bot when you tap or click an Inline Button it triggers an Intent and displays a UI like in this picture [image: So when you click the Inline Button Pay$142]

So when you click the Inline Button Pay$142 it calls an Intent and displays this UI form [image]

It Calls this UI form.

How does one do that?

Here is My Code

Here is my Main Class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Initialize Api Context
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
// Instantiate Telegram Bots API
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
// Register our bot
        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new UI());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is where i have defined my Inline Keyboard Button

```
public class UI extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
// We check if the update has a message and the message has text
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String message_text = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/start")) {
                SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object

                        .setChatId(chat_id)
                        .setText("You send /start");
                InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

                List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
                List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();

                rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("Update message text").setCallbackData("update_msg_text"));
// Set the keyboard to the markup
                rowsInline.add(rowInline);
// Add it to the message
                markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
                message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
                try {
                    execute(message); // Sending our message objexecute(message); // Sending our message obj

                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
            }
        } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
// Set variables
            String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
            long message_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();

            long chat_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();
            if (call_data.equals("update_msg_text")) {
                String answer = "Updated message text";
                EditMessageText new_message = new EditMessageText()    

                        .setChatId(chat_id)
                        .setMessageId(toIntExact(message_id))
                        .setText(answer);
                try {
                    execute(new_message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        // Return bot username
        // If bot username is @MyAmazingBot, it must return 'MyAmazingBot

        return BOTUSERNAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
// Return bot token from BotFather
        return BOTTOKEN;
    }

}
```

How does one call an Intent using a Telegram Bot?
Thank You.

Comment: Please refer to https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments

Answer (score 0):

You find an introduction to the payments in telegram in core.telegram.org/bots/payments like Sean allready commented.
The ShopBot is just a bot by the Telegram Team to showcase the Telegram Bot Payments API, it's just an  example.

I'm not quite sure if you are using a library or framework for it... if yes, i think you aren't using it quite right.

You can find the whole Bot API documentation at core.telegram.org/bots/api and in the [Payments-Section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#payments) you can read about the methods and objects related to the payment system in telegram.

What you tried (using Inline Keyboard) is not really the payment api. Most of the ui you see when using ShopBot is not customisable, it is only useable with the payment api.